# Is it possible to use trained classification neural network to generate data?

Tags: machine-learning, deep-learning, neural-network, classification

If i reverse image classification NN and feed it with some class label will it generate image?

Comment: I understand that i can't make high quality object in multiple dimension from low dimension. But still, what kind of image will it generate and will that image contain any useful information, i wonder.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No it won't work like this. A Neural Network is a non-invertible function.

If instead you start from internal representations, apparently it's possible to do something: https://arxiv.org/abs/2107.06304